# dpkg-deb: error

Tags: 22.04, arm64

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvulkan1_1.3.204.1-2_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I got this on Ubuntu 22.04, any solution for this?

Comment: Please include more details in your question - which command exactly gives this output? And please provide full output, not only a few lines.